# Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there anyway to get Eclipse to automatically look for static imports? For example, now that I've finally upgraded to Junit 4, I'd like to be able to write:

```
assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and have Eclipse add:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Maybe I'm asking too much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have to manually add static imports all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435598/do-i-have-to-manually-add-static-imports-all-the-time)

Answer (score 588, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse Europa, which also has the Favorite preference section:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites

In mine, I have the following entries (when adding, use "New Type" and omit the `.*`):

```
org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*
org.junit.*
org.junit.Assert.*
org.junit.Assume.*
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*
```

All but the third of those are static imports. By having those as favorites, if I type "`assertT`" and hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**, Eclipse offers up `assertThat` as a suggestion, and if I pick it, it will add the proper static import to the file.

Comment: Yeah awesome, but, Dude, you only have the matchers for hamcrest. That doesn't bring in AssertThat.. ?

Comment: [assertThat](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29)  is on Assert

Comment: If you try this in Eclipse 4.2 "Juno" it forbids appending the `.*`, so you must manually enter `New Member` -> `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` and so on. Anyone have a better workaround for this?

Comment: Ah - the trick is to simply add `org.junit.Assert` via `New Type...`, the `.*` is then implicit.

Comment: Is it correct that auto-import `Ctrl+Shift+o` won't add the necessary import, and in fact you must hover the cursor and choose `Add static import..` option? It's a shame the usual auto-import selection list dialog doesn't display.

Comment: This does not work anymore. I added the entries exactly as shown, but am now offered anything if I type "asserte" and and ctrl+space. Any ideas ?

Comment: @J.Stoever - If you're using JUnit 4 you'll want to use the Hamcrest form: `assertThat(value, is(expected));`

Comment: Also use Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> Select Organize imports . It automatically organizes your imports everytime you save. So need of using any shortcuts.

Comment: I was trying to get `assertEquals(...)`. In Eclipse kepler 4.3, I tried `asserte` followed by ctrl+space. It gets me all methods that begin with `asserte`. Thanks.

Comment: You can also put the number of imports required to use `.*` in the static import to 1. But beware that in that case you shouldn't use static imports on classes that contain class members with names that are too generic (e.g. don't use static import with `.*` for classes with `getInstance`).

Comment: I tried this with Eclipse Kepler, but to no avail. I restarted Eclipse as well. No autocompletion, no static import choice when hovvering or pressing CTRL + 1. Anyone experienced this?

Comment: Intellij Idea supports this out of the box. Shame eclipse doesn't.

Answer (score 245):

If you highlight the method `Assert.assertEquals(val1, val2)` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (Add Import), it will add it as a static import, at least in Eclipse 3.4.

Comment: In Eclipse Juno I've only managed to make it work if I highlight only the method and afterwards use the CTRL + SHIFT + M.

Comment: Works also for static fields A.X -> X (hightly A.X and Ctrl + Shift + M).
Thanks. Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Works for me on Luna.  Make sure your cursor is on the right side of the period.  Wish I had learned about this years ago!

Comment: @yair - does not work for me too in Kepler 4.3 `assertEquals(3, team.getGamesWon())`

Comment: UPDATE: works on Eclipse **Mars**. Just place cursor somewhere on the method.

Answer (score 31):

Eclipse 3.4 has a Favourites section under Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist

If you use `org.junit.Assert` a lot, you might find some value to adding it there.

Answer (score 22):

Not exactly what I wanted, but I found a workaround. In Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede),  go to

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist

and check the checkbox for **Use static imports (only 1.5 or higher)**.

This will not bring in the import on an Optimize Imports, but if you do a Quick Fix (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) on the line it will give you the option to add the static import which is good enough.

Answer (score 10):

From [Content assist for static imports](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html)

> To get content assist proposals for static members configure your list of favorite static members on the  Opens the Favorites preference page `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites` preference page.
>   For example, if you have added `java.util.Arrays.*` or `org.junit.Assert.*` to this list, then all static methods of this type matching the completion prefix will be added to the proposals list.

Open `Window » Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For SpringFramework Tests, I would recommend to add the below as well

```
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcResponseBuilders
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
org.mockito.Mockito
```

When you add above as new Type it automatically add .* to the package.

Answer (score 6):

Shortcut for static import:
    CTRL + SHIFT + M

Answer (score 2):

Select the constant, type

```
Ctrl + 1  (quick fix)
```

Select "Convert to static import." from the drop down.

"Quick fix" has options even though it is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 4.9, you can static import existing invocations using a quick fix.

> A new quick fix has been implemented that allows the user to convert static field accesses and static methods to use a static import. It's also possible to replace all occurrences at the same time.

[More details here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#convert-to-static-import)