# How to start using Objectify v4?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

This looks like an absurd question but I am having problem with starting to code with Objectify v4 in appengine.

The introduction on objectify page says that you should use **ofy** to do all the operations. 
For this they have shown this to use

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

Thing th = ofy().load().key(thingKey).get();
```

Now the thing is in my eclipse auto suggestion it is not showing my **ofy()**  thing. 
When I am importing the first line which I have written above it shows error.

I just want to know how to get ofy() to use?

Thanks

Comment: Which Java compiler version do you use? Which is the exact error message? Did you check your classpath?

Comment: Do you have the Objectify JAR in your project?

Comment: @PixelElephant Well it seems that I had downloaded the Objectify something with **4a** written on it. that was the only problem. When I replaced it with **4b01** it started working. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the correct jar is on your build path, have you adjusted your content assist favorite settings?  At the least it might throw an error that may help you.

From: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Setup

> Enable static imports in Eclipse
>
> This step is optional, but will help prevent you from typing ObjectifyService.ofy() over >and over again.
>
> Eclipse does not automatically add static imports when you Organize Imports. By default, >it won't even complete static imports when you type ofy[cmd-space]. If you want to save >yourself a lot of typing, add a "Favorite" static import for ObjectifyService.ofy().
>
> **Visit Window » Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites and add:**
> com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy
>
> Now, when you type ofy[cmd-space], Eclipse will add a static import for you.

[Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports) may also help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your first line was the answer. See my comment above.