# Eclipse : transform static method invocation to a static import

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

Is there a way to transform automatically this static method invocation (`Arrays.asList`):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

to this invocation using a `static import`:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.List;

public class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = asList("hello", "world");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I know that i can configure the code completion using this `Window » Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites`as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports).

My question is about transforming an **existing** static method invocation. Ideally, i would like do not have to configure a "favorite import".

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Put the cursor on the method name (`asList`) and press `Ctrl-Shift-M`.

This is the default keyboard shortcut for the 'Add Import' command. You can also find the command on the 'Source' menu.

Comment: Thanks! Gold worthy!

Comment: Thanks! but if has many `Arrays.asList`, only remove `Arrays` of this current cursor line.

Comment: @zhuguowei, bummer ! :(