# Eclipse remove a static import

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-refactoring

With eclipse i can easily transform the static invocation to

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

to a static import:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.List;

public class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = asList("hello", "world");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I [put the cursor on the method name (`asList`) and press `Ctrl-Shift-M`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569507/1594933) (`Add Import`).

Now, for some refactoring reasons, i want to remove the static import and get back to the first code:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
```

Is there a shorcut quickly do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove an (`static`) `import` statement with a shortcut, unless it's **unused**.

So, first comment out the statement:

```
//List<String> list = asList("hello", "world");
```

Then, activate the shortcut for Organizing Import Statements (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) and the unused `import` statements will be automatically removed.

Finally, uncomment the line you commented first and refactor it so it compiles:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the trick i use to do. Note that you have to import `java.util.Arrays` again at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's a former question:

You can do that using Eclipse Cleanup or Eclipse Save Action.

Warning: It looks like a bug to me but unchecking the options doesn't perform the opposite action.

Cleanup:

- Go to Preferences > Java > Code Style > Cleanup
- Click on Edit
- Go to member accesses tab
- In Static accesses section, check Qualify field accesses, qualify methode accesses
- Right Click on the file > Source > Cleanup

Puntual cleanup:

- Right click on the file > Source > CLeanup
- Use custom profile
- Go to member accesses tab
- In Static accesses section, check Qualify field accesses, qualify methode accesses
- Right Click on the file > Source > Cleanup
- Apply > OK

Save action:

- Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Save action
- Check "Additional actions"
- Go to member accesses tab
- In Static accesses section, check Qualify field accesses, qualify methode accesses
- Just save the file