# Eclipse/IntelliJ: static imports of members

Tags: eclipse, static, import, intellij-idea, member

I'm refactoring something affecting many bits of my code (huge), and I ended up in needing to organise the import of my project so it can add a static import of a member in a class..

After having spent a full day trying to figure out how to do that, I can't find the way. It's not working neither in IntelliJ or in Eclipse.

In Eclipse I have added it to the Favorites settings, just like it is explained here:

[Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports)

But, it only works on the Control + space, not on Control+Shift+O (to rearrange imports)

In Eclipse 4.2 at least it draws the line red and propose me the suggestion to add the import, but it  still doing nothing on the "Organise Import" trigger.

In IntelliJ it is the same, adding the package and the class to the setting, fixes the Control+Alt+Space, but it doesn't deal with the "Optimise Import" feature.

I can't believe this. Has anybody had to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to perform `import static` on just everything; if the class contains class members that are too general, then an `import static` will only make your code unreadable. Besides that, there may be name clashes (e.g. two classes having a `static getInstance()` method would be quite common.

With IntelliJ 13.1.3 you can hit Alt-ENTER, then choose to do a static import (older versions may require one or more CTR-Space before the Alt-ENTER. If you do this on a static member then only the static member is statically imported. If you do it on a class you can do to statically import everything (e.g. `import static some.package.SomeClass.*`). In the latter case it will remove the class in front of the static imports, *unless* there is a name clash.

Beware, even if there is no name clash, doing things like `SomeInterface someInstance = getInstance()` - where `getInstance()` was statically imported - will get your colleagues *very nervous*.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-read the question you referred to. You missed [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289289/44089) mentioning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. There is a difference between the commands "Organize Imports" and "Add import".

Comment: Add import (ctrl+shift+m) replaces this structure:
   AnyClass.anyMember
   into
   anyMember
by adding the import static, but if I already have
anyMember, it doesn't help and does nothing.