# Eclipse optimize imports to include static members and methods

Tags: eclipse, junit

Long user of eclipse and Java.  One issue that i've found with Eclipse, is it seems that there is no easy way to import static members and methods.

Namely, the jUnit `fail()` method from `org.junit.Assert`

I create several classes a day, and manually add

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
```

to the import statements.  This is quite annoying.  I absolute LOVE using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to organize my imports, but it still doesn't find `static` members and methods.

Also, the import does not show up in eclipse.
[image]

Funny thing is, is that i've seen it work previously, but i cant recall the variables.

#### So to my question:

Does anybody know what I need to do to ensure that this static import is always recognized and can be found using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>?

---

Thanks @qqilihq.

#### Note:

The answer that was accepted does not work with the Organize Imports keyboard shortcut that I preferred in eclipse, but does work for the "hover over" suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports)

Comment: This question was asked 5 years previous to that question there.  I've updated the title though, to better show the intent. 

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did you have a look at **Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites**? You can define candidates for static imports there. Result:

[image]

For less used classes you can lower the value of `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports > Number of static imports needed for .*` but beware that you may get `.*` for classes that contain generically named methods such as `getInstance`. This in turn may lead to confusion and/or naming conflicts.

Comment: that definitely worked!  and judging by the description of that particular functionality in eclipse, looks like it's specifically designed for my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @sircapsalot For less used classes you can lower the value of `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports > Number of static imports needed for .*` but beware that you may get `.*` for classes that e.g. contain a `getInstance` method. qqilihq, should I include this in the answer or should I create a separate one?

Comment: I'm actually using IntelliJ IDEA now.  much smarter editor. I don't have to do these favorites anymore :)

Comment: @sircapsalot Yeah, smarter editor, less smart parsing/compiling. I guess you cannot have your cake and eat it. I'm "stuck" with Eclipse due to a specific plugin I require...

Comment: For those who can't get it to work, make sur you add the correct line in the config. In the context of this question, it is "org.junit.Assert.*" and not "org.junit.Assert.fail"

Answer (score 34):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, for example you want to import verify method from Mockito class then

`Mockito.verify() // select verify and press Ctrl + Shift + M`

This will import verify static method from Mockito class.

Comment: What would that do? Here, nothing happens.

Comment: It imports the currently highlighted static method.

Comment: Ah, took me some time to figure out the timing, but also cool.

Comment: not working in mac. i have tried with cmd + shift + M

Comment: This also works with static field imports. I wish I could give you a million up-votes.

Comment: This only works if you have already imported the class itself first, threw me for a loop until I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

You can add the classes that you statically import from **Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites** page in Eclipse. Then, Ctrl+Space shortcut lists all the static members of your favourite classes in the content assist menu.