# how to make Scala IDE/ Intelij import scala.concurrent.duration._

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-ide

I am new to Scala, and many times i see code like this

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
```

with Intelij, I could press `alt + enter` to import Timeout. But can't for `5 seconds`. Have to search google to remember the `duration._`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can define templates, such that every new scala file will have the desired import statement. However, I hardly believe you need this in every file? Since it could be anything, you want to import (based on the class name), I guess IntelliJ will have to do some querying..

Comment: I copy that code to Intelij, it will show error that unknow Timeout. I move mouse to the line & press `alt + enter`, then I could import `akka.util.Timeout`, but not for `5 seconds`, then I have to google some where to copy `scala.concurrent.duration._`. with Eclipse there is static template definition, that I could add [static import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
```

is actually means

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(duration.DurationInt(5).seconds)
```

where "DurationInt" is implicit convertion function.

Unfortunatelly both IDEs are unable to search for implicit conversions to import. So if you want them to add import statemtn automtically try second variant.

Comment: ok let this be my day. I don't like fancy word like `Timeout (5 seconds)`